# Using the Optaplanner algorithm to solve, how can I set the solution to automatically stop when the optimal solution is found?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

Using Optaplanner to solve the problem, I configured the first fit algorithm. At present, I can only set a fixed time for the solution. Even if the optimal solution has been found in advance, I need to continue to wait for the end of the solution. How can I set the solution to stop automatically when the optimal solution is found?

Comment: I know nothing of optaplanner, but are you sure that it *knows* when a given solution is optimal?

Comment: I can observe the change in the score, and if the score does not change within the time frame, I understand that the best solution should be reached.

Comment: that just means that the score is no longer improving. In general that doesn't *necessarily* that the best solution is found. The optimizer might be stuck in a local optimum and will never find the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: if you *know* what the optimal solution to your problem is, then you don't need OptaPlanner :)

Presuming you really have an optimization problem, then you don't know how an optimal solution looks like, what its score is, neither how to find it. You only have a scoring function that is used to quickly compare quality of different solutions.

With a good local search algorithm configuration, OptaPlanner will keep providing you with better and better solutions with varying frequency. And *you will never know* if the last solution OptaPlanner has found is the optimal one.

You have a couple of basic options to tell OptaPlanner when to stop solving:

1. You have a limited time to spend optimizing the problem. Then use [time based termination](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#timeMillisSpentTermination).
2. You have a rough idea what the score of a "good enough" solution should be. Then use [best score termination](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#bestScoreTermination).
3. You have a vague idea of the time available for solving. Then you can think: if OptaPlanner is unable to improve the solution for say 1 hour, then stop. Use [unimproved time spent termination](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#unimprovedTimeMillisSpentTermination) for that.
4. Finally, you can [terminate solving asynchronously](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#asynchronousTermination) based on some external event (user's decision, etc.).

Comment: Technically, I think it is possible to design a scoring function that reaches 0 when the solution is optimal. For some problems, at least. (See nqueens.) So even though you do not know what the optimal solution is, you still know to stop at score 0.

Comment: When the score no longer changes, I understand that it has reached the best solution it can find, and if the time set at this time has not been reached, it will continue to waste time. So if the best score can be found in advance within the time frame we set, and the score remains unchanged, can this situation be automatically terminated early?

Comment: See (3): unimproved time spent termination (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#unimprovedTimeMillisSpentTermination). If you want the solver to terminate when it cannot improve within 5 minutes, use `<unimprovedMinutesSpentLimit>5</unimprovedMinutesSpentLimit>`. Combine multiple terminations with OR so it terminates within a time limit or when it can no longer improve the score: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#combiningMultipleTerminations

Answer (score 3):

OptaPlanner does not know what the best solution is. If you know what the best solution is, you can have it [terminate when that solution is reached](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#bestScoreTermination).

Comment: When the score no longer changes, I understand that it has reached the best solution it can find, and if the time set at this time has not been reached, it will continue to waste time. So if the best score can be found in advance within the time frame we set, and the score remains unchanged, can this situation be automatically terminated early?

Comment: Already answered in the comments below the preferred answer.